# Как отправить корректно POST запрос на WebApi C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

Взялся за изучение NetCore. Захотел проверить самописное WebApi на простых запросах используя JavaScript.
С Get запросами все понятно а вот как отправить корректный POST запрос на сторону WebApi я не понимаю.

Вот мой запрос на стороне клиента

```
PostRequest.onclick = function () {

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = request.responseText;


request.open("POST", "api/home");
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(dataForApi.value);
}
```

Но как мне принять на стороне сервера корректно, по умолчанию метод POST имеет такой вид

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {

    }
```

У меня есть подозрение, что ошибка на стороне клиента в параметре

```
 request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Content-Type не корректный. Но я почти все перепробовал, доходит до того, что метод просто не "дергает" на стороне Api.

Comment: Для проверки АПИ используйте инструменты типа [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), сэкономите кучу времени и нервов.

Comment: @tym32167 Самое забавное, что в Постмане все работает.. Но ошибку нашел все же. Не правильно передавал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выглядят данные, которые вы передаёте? Попробуйте так: request.send("value=" + dataForApi.value).